# Separating 2d array value into separate variables

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array in Java.

For example, `[['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']].`

And let's say I wanted to access element `'f'` which would be represented as element `[1][2]`.

How would I split the `1` and `2` up so  that they can be stored in separate variables (e.g. `int x` and `int y`)?

Comment: ? `private int x; private int y;` ? and then `myArray[x][y]`, ... perhaps. I'm not really sure what you're asking.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: @JimGarrison: agree, one that would benefit from inclusion of more key information

Answer (score 1):

## Write a class

Write a class to represent the coordinate location within your matrix.

Use [records](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395) to declare a class whose purpose is to communicate data transparently and immutably. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

```
record MatrixCoordinate( int rowIndex , int columnIndex ) { }
```

Instantiate like any class.

```
MatrixCoordinate mc = new MatrixCoordinate( 1 , 2 );
```

Collect such objects for multiple coordinates.

```java
List < MatrixCoordinate > coordinates =
        List.of(
                new MatrixCoordinate( 1 , 2 ) ,
                new MatrixCoordinate( 0 , 1 )
        );
```

To access the coordinates, call the implicitly defined accessor (getter) methods. The accessor name by default is the name of the field property.

Complete example.

```java
package work.basil.example.recs;

import java.util.List;

public class App2
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        record MatrixCoordinate( int rowIndex , int columnIndex ) { }
        List < MatrixCoordinate > coordinates =
                List.of(
                        new MatrixCoordinate( 1 , 2 ) ,
                        new MatrixCoordinate( 0 , 1 )
                );

        int[][] arr =
                {
                        { 1 , 2 , 3 } ,
                        { 4 , 3 , 6 } ,
                        { 7 , 8 , 9 }
                };

        for ( MatrixCoordinate coordinate : coordinates )
        {
            int x = arr[ coordinate.rowIndex ][ coordinate.columnIndex ];
            System.out.println( coordinate + " = " + x );
        }
    }
}
```

When run:

```
MatrixCoordinate[rowIndex=1, columnIndex=2] = 6
MatrixCoordinate[rowIndex=0, columnIndex=1] = 2
```